# How to plot the proportion or count of items given a datetime?

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, seaborn

I have the following pandas dataframe:

```
year       | id
---------------
2001-08-10 | 1
2002-08-31 | 1
2003-08-29 | 1
2006-06-21 | 3
2002-03-27 | 3
2003-07-14 | 1
2004-06-15 | 2
2003-08-14 | 2
2003-07-29 | 2
2011-02-21 | 3
2011-01-02 | 4
2012-04-29 | 2
2013-05-29 | 1
```

I would like to plot the proportion of ids per year? I tried to:

```
df.groupby([df2["year"].dt.year]).count().plot(kind="barh")
```

However, I dont really think this shows the proportion of ids per year. Furthermore, I have a lot of ids (from 1 to 60). Therefore, which is the correct way to plot a big number of datetimes and ids?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can using `crosstab`

```
df.year=pd.to_datetime(df.year)
pd.crosstab(df.year.dt.year,df.id).plot(kind='bar',stacked=True)
```

[image]

Comment: @tumbleweed would you like show your expected output ?

Comment: its the same that you proposed

Comment: @tumbleweed base on my experience , this method should be efficiency

Comment: I got this exception: `ValueError: Image size of 391x91210 pixels is too large. It must be less than 2^16 in each direction.`

Comment: @tumbleweed plot whole dataframe is kind of hard for pandas, since graph is to better understanding the data(after summaries ), assuming you can plot that data in a bar or other plot type , how can we using that 'big' plot present the data ?

Comment: yes youre right.. which other way of visualize this do you recommend me ?

Comment: @tumbleweed I will do it with violinplot from seaborn : `sns.violinplot(x="year", y="id", data=df.assign(year=df.year.str[:4]))`, but for doing this the number of count will not obvious